# Java for loop where values jump

Tags: java, for-loop

If I have three variables and I want a value in a for loop to jump from one to the next, how would I do that? You can assume the first variable is the smallest and the third is the biggest, and that the variables are not equal to one another(although if there is a way to do it where they are equal that would be good).

I have an example for if it was only two values.

```
int val1 = 5;
int val2 = 9;
for(int i = val1; i <= val2; i=i+(val2-val1) {
}
```

In this case `i` would first be 5, and then 9. Also, is there any way to do it with a different amount of variables?

Comment: Put the values in an `Array` and then loop over the values in the `Array`

Comment: In java 8 or higher, use Stream.of(val1,val2,val3).forEach

Comment: @GonenI What is Stream.of?

Comment: Maybe put the body of your for-loop logic in a method and call it: foo(val1); foo(val2); foo(val3); ?  How many variables will you have ?  If you're dealing with 2 or 3 then a for-loop seems complicated.  If you're going to deal with dozens or hundreds then the comments + answers suggesting a list seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can place those in an array and access to it by index

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        int[] myArray = {4, 6 , 9};
        for(int x : myArray)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        //or....

        for(int x =0; x<3; x++)
        {
            System.out.println(myArray[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% certain I understand your question, but you could do

```
for(int i = val1; i <= val2; i = (i == val1) ? val2 : val2+1) {
    // ...
}
```

If you need more values, I would put them in an array and use a `for-each` loop over that

```
int[] vals = {5,9,17};
for (int i : vals) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I understand the array method, but how does the incrementation work? If it isn't `val1` shouldnt it just make it `val3`?

Comment: @NabilotexD Ternary operator. if `i` is `val1` change it to `val2`. Otherwise make it `val2 + 1` (to end the loop).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch this of course requires the values to be in ascending order, and smaller than max_value.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gonen I said, you can handle this using `stream`. If you want  '...the first variable is the smallest and the third is the biggest...' you should use `stream.sorted()` to get sorted values.

`x` corresponds to each one element of the `vals` list while traversing. So you can do whatever you want in the `forEach` block with using `x`

```
List<Integer> vals = Arrays.asList(5,9,17);

vals.stream().sorted().forEach(x -> {
    System.out.println(x);
});
```

Comment: It says it can't find `List`

Comment: you should add imports: `import java.util.List;`

Comment: I'm adding some explanation, please ask for points that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

If we are already being a bit silly, this will do the trick for as many values as you want, and inside a for loop. But I would never actually write code like this because its completely unreadable:

```
package package1;

public class SillySkip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for( int data[] = {5,10,-4}, i, j=0; j < data.length && (i = data[j]) % 1 == 0 ; ++j )
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

From Java 8 and up you can use Stream.of to iterate arbitrary values like this:

```
package package1;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class IterateSomeValues {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Stream.of(5,10,-4).forEach(e->System.out.println(e));
        }

    }
```